# An 'x' or a 'x'?

Tags: indefinite-articles, mathematics

Suppose that 'x' is a variable in a Mathematics text. What is more correct to say:

a. Pick an 'x' *or*

b. pick a 'x'?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [*the* most frequently asked ELU question of all time](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent).